# Axis title doesn't show up in Plotly.NET for C#

Tags: c#, plot, plotly.net

I start using Plotly.NET for plotting. Everything was OK until I start plot 3D surfaces and my axis title disappear.

There is part of the code

```
my_func(double[] x, string[] y, double[,] z)

//...

LinearAxis xAxis = LinearAxis();
xAxis.SetValue("title", "axis title");

Layout layout = new Layout();
layout.SetValue("xaxis", xAxis);

Trace surface = new Trace("surface");
surface.SetValue("x", x);
surface.SetValue("y", y);
surface.SetValue("z", z);

GenericChart.ofTraceObject(true, surface).WithLayout(layout: layout).Show();
```

And axis still the default.

[There is plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl0OV.png)

I want to change AxisTitle and to know what the problem is

Please help

I try to use Plotly.NET.CSharp instead Plotly.NET

I also try this construction:

```
 Chart.Surface<double, double, double,string>(
        zData: new double[][] {new double[]{1,1}, new double[]{1,1}},
        X: new double[] { 1, 2 }, 
        Y: new double[] { 5, 10 })
   .WithXAxisStyle<double, double, string>(Title: Plotly.NET.Title.init("xAxis"))
   .WithYAxisStyle<double, double, string>(Title: Plotly.NET.Title.init("yAxis"))
   .Show();
```

It doesn't help, but other functions such as `WithSize, WithTraceInfo` and etc. work fine

```
Chart.Surface<double, double, double,string>(zData: new double[][] {new double[]{1,1}, new double[]{1,1}},
        X: new double[] { 1, 2 }, 
        Y: new double[] { 5, 10 },  ShowScale: false)
.WithSize(1500,1500).WithTraceInfo(Name: "Name", ShowLegend: true, LegendGroupTitle: Plotly.NET.Title.init("TITLE") )
    .Show();
```

[This is plot in Plotly.NET.CSharp with custom size and etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smtp7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with the lowest API level of Plotly.NET, where you set values directly on the objects (via `SetValue`). To use this layer effectively, you have to know how plotls.js (the library Plotly.NET uses) expects values. More on the different API layers can for example be read in our [paper](https://f1000research.com/articles/11-1094)

In the case of axis objects on 3D plots, plotly.js schema differs from 2D cartesian plots by having a `scene` object which contains the x, y, and z axis instead of directly using the layout's `xaxis` and `yaxis` attributes (more [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/scene/#layout-scene-xaxis)).

So with that knowledge, you can set axis objects on 3D plots via initializing a scene object:

```cs
var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();
var y = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();
var z = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();

LinearAxis xAxis = new LinearAxis();
xAxis.SetValue("title", "x axis title");
LinearAxis yAxis = new LinearAxis();
yAxis.SetValue("title", "y axis title");
LinearAxis zAxis = new LinearAxis();
zAxis.SetValue("title", "z axis title");

Scene scene = new Scene();
scene.SetValue("xaxis", xAxis);
scene.SetValue("yaxis", yAxis);
scene.SetValue("zaxis", zAxis);

Layout layout = new Layout();
layout.SetValue("scene", scene);

Trace point = new Trace("scatter3d");
point.SetValue("x", x);
point.SetValue("y", y);
point.SetValue("z", z);

GenericChart.ofTraceObject(trace:point, useDefaults: true)
.WithLayout(layout)
```

[image: plot result]

## Edit for Plotly.NET.CSharp

in Plotly.NET.CSharp, you must set the `Id` argument of the `WithAxisStyle` methods to `Scene` like this:

```cs
using Plotly.NET.CSharp;

Chart.Surface<double, double, double,string>(
    zData: new double[][] {new double[]{1,1}, new double[]{1,1}},
    X: new double[] { 1, 2 }, 
    Y: new double[] { 5, 10 })
.WithXAxisStyle<double, double, string>(Title: Plotly.NET.Title.init("xAxis"), Id: Plotly.NET.StyleParam.SubPlotId.Scene.NewScene(1))
.WithYAxisStyle<double, double, string>(Title: Plotly.NET.Title.init("yAxis"), Id: Plotly.NET.StyleParam.SubPlotId.Scene.NewScene(1))
```

[image: plot result for Plotly.NET.CSharp]